# What role if any did Ligachev play in the 1991 coup attempt against Gorbachev?

Tags: soviet-union, coup

[Ligachev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yegor_Ligachyov) was the head of the we-love-Brezhnevism club in the last days of the Soviet Union. Was he at all involved in the bring-back-Brezhnevism coup in 1991? If not, what did he do and say in that period?

Edit: their main target may have been [Yeltsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Yeltsin), but they locked up [Gorbachev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Gorbachev) in his dacha and appointed a new 'acting President'. That sounds like it's against Gorbachev to me but I suppose that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: fun fact: Ligachev was born pretty much in the same time as USSR, and he is still alive.

Comment: Are you sure that their plan was "bring-back-Brezhnevism"? Given that the chief mastermind behind the coup was Kruchkov, "Andropovism" might be even likelier.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, in 1991 he was already 70 years old. He laid in the hospital.

[From the interview in Komsomolskaya Pravda, 2011](http://www.kp.ru/daily/25813.3/2791269)

> **Почему ГКЧП провалился?**
>   Потому что они не были связаны с партийными организациями. Партийные организации на местах ждали сигнала. *Я в это время в больнице был*, но я знаю настроения людей.

Rough translation:

> "**Why did the GKCHP fail?** Because they were not connected with party organizations.  Party organizations in the field were waiting for a signal.  At that time I was in the hospital, but I know the mood of the people."

BTW. This is not right, saying that GKCHP's coup was against Gorbachev. The primary target was Yeltsin. The fact is, they didn't arrest Gorbachev, because sought a way to cooperate with him. Of course, he was considered too weak to keep the seat for a long time. But as the future events showed, Gorbachev was going to lose in any case.

Comment: Very convenient for him. Perhaps too convenient....

Comment: So from the sound of it, he was in favour... I wonder if he made any statement at the time. I know he was old but he's actually still alive today!

Comment: @FelixGoldberg He had no real power. I'm inclined to think that he wasn't really invited.

Comment: @NeMo If you lived in USSR in 1991 you would realize how funny your "making statements" sounds. How? To whom? I can only remember two statements: by GKCHP and by Gorbachev from Foros.

Comment: Presumably if he had wanted to show verbal support for the coup, the Gang of Eight-controlled media would have been only too eager to publish his remarks. If he was opposed, after the coup was defeated pro-Yeltsin media would certainly have no reason to hide that.

Comment: The wikipedia article says the Gang of Eight allowed some pro-coup papers to continue publishing. Admittedly it's only wikipedia, so that could be wrong.

Comment: @NeMo GKCHP was really bad in PR. They showed the ballet on TV all day long. No surprising if some people sympathizing them had no possibility to say that.

Comment: @NeMo And after these events Yeltsin's priority was to take the power from Gorbachev. The guys of GKCHP were forgotten very soon. So no one even remembered of Ligachev.

Comment: The argument of the answer does not seem to be valid: (1) the coup has been prepared for almost 1½ years, and Ligachev obviously was not hospitalized all that time; (2) Yakovlev in his memories (`А.Н. Яковлев "Омут памяти"`) clearly says that Ligachev was one of the ideologists of the neo-soviet coup of GKChP ("gang of eight"), albeit he did not become a member of the gang.

Comment: @bytebuster (1) The former GKCHP members never confirm such long term (2) Yakovlev, being on the other side, couldn't know anything definite about Ligachev's role, except his own dislike of the old adversary. What's more important is that Ligachev never was under investigation, even though he had no friends to cover him. Say, Lukyanov was arrested, though he didn't participated in the putsch, but Ligachev wasn't. I can only think of one reason: Ligachev became a political corpse long before that.